# How can I best create a SharePoint list view that shows only root folder contents?

Tags: sharepoint, list-definition

I have a custom SharePoint list definition that is based on the Document content type.  My library instance that I create from this contains many HTML documents, and each of those documents has some images saved into a subfolder inside this library.  What's the best way to create a view that will show all of those top-level HTML documents without showing all of the image accessory files?  I'd prefer to define this within the schema.xml file for my list definition.

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding Scope="FilesOnly" to the View tag in your list definition should do the trick.